# MongoDB & Java, add a value to the result

Tags: java, mongodb

I have the code as shown below. I query the MongoDB and the results are serialized and returned. But I would like to add a new value to every record/document, in this case 'age'.
So I thought I would loop over the results and add them with one.put but the value is not showing in the returned json.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help or suggestions!

```
    public String (int id){     
        DBCollection collection = database.getCollection("collection");
        BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
        query.put("id", id);

        DBCursor cursor = collection.find(query);       
        if (cursor.hasNext()) {
            DBObject one = cursor.next();
            one.put("age", 33);
        }

        String json = JSON.serialize(cursor)

        return json;
    }
```

Comment: The returned json is being used for output. And in this output I need to add a value, it doesn't have to be saved in the database.

Comment: you are creating a new DBObject once inside "if" and then you are not saving it anywhere.  The new field only exists in "one" - an object that only has scope within the "if" statement.  By the way, you don't have a loop anywhere - I suggest you loop over the cursor appending each record *with* the new field added to a new list and then output that list (serialized).

Comment: Sorry, I don't fully understand.Do you have a code example?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky Is List the correct data structure here. Don't we need a map.

Comment: the point is you need to accumulate the results somewhere - technically you will need a list of maps.  And you need a loop.  You have neither here...

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to **inject** an attribute into the result without saving the change in the database, I would suggest the following implementation:

```
public String getJSONString(int id) {     
    DBCollection collection = database.getCollection("collection");
    DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("id", id);

    List<DBObject> objects = collection.find(query).toArray();       
    for (DBObject obj : objects) {
        obj.put("age", 33);
    }

    return JSON.serialize(objects)
}
```

Note that all objects **have to be kept in memory** if implemented in this way.

BTW: You don't loop over the cursor in your original post (`if` instead of `while`). Furthermore the cursor should always be [closed](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.9.3/com/mongodb/DBCursor.html#close%28%29) in a finally block.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't try this, but it looks to me it should work. Typo with the if/while. Thanks for the comment to close the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt whether the cursor will be updated with the new put, since it is for the existing query.

**EDIT** :
For adding a new value, I would recommend two solutions.

1. Map the JSON document to a POJO and then call the appropriate setter. This a cleaner and extensible approach.
2. Copy the values to a Map and then add the final key:value which is age:33 in this case.

**For Saving the updated obj**

You are not calling `save` on the `collection`.

Refer to [Saving objects](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Java+-+Saving+Objects+Using+DBObject) in Mongo Documentation for more, especially the last part that explains the update.

Comment: Hi, the returned json is being used for output. And in this output I need to add a value, it doesn't have to be saved in the database.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got it working in the end, by using an ArrayList:

```
        public String (int id){     
            DBCollection collection = database.getCollection("collection");
            BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
            query.put("id", id);

            ArrayList<DBObject> al = new ArrayList<DBObject>();     
            while(cursor.hasNext()){
                DBObject one = cursor.next();        
                one.put("age", 33);
                al.add(one);
            }       

            String json = JSON.serialize(al)

            return json;
        }
```